# Is it safe to use a 128 bits key in HMAC-SHA256?

Tags: cryptography, hmac

Facebook app secret is a string of 32 characters (0-9, a-f) and thus it represents a 128 bits byte array. [Facebook uses this as the key to generate signed request using HMAC-SHA256](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). Is this a correct usage? I thought HMAC-SHA256 should use 256 bits keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page says that the 256bit [*signature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is derived from a *payload* (what facebook is signing) + your 128 bit [*salt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

So yes, it sounds like correct usage.

The secret 16 bytes (32 characters) isn't actually a key in the sense that it's used to encrypt and decrypt something.  Rather, it's a bit of data (a salt) that is used to alter the result of the digital signature, by changing the input ever-so-slightly, so that only someone who knew the exact secret and the exact payload could have created the signature.

Comment: No, it use [PHP's `hash_hmac` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) where the third argument is `$secret`. See this line `$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);`

Comment: `Returns a string containing the calculated message digest`.  A message digest is the same thing as a signature, and in this case, the term *key* is synonymous with the concept of *salting*.  Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code shows that *key* is concatenated onto the payload before hashing.

Comment: A 128-bit strength for the secret means just that.  You benefit from that strength if someone tries to guess your secret and fraudulently sign malicious payloads to pretend they came from facebook.  Whatever number of bits the hashing function produces isn't strictly related.

Comment: You're right, I meant whatever 128 divide 8 would be, but wrote 32 bytes (before the update).

Comment: @antak A message digest is not the same thing as a signature. I think you've confused it with a message authentication code, which is what HMAC provides. Furthermore, the HMAC key is a key and it is not a salt, it is integrated using a mixing function described in the specification; it's not just prepended unless it's an incorrect implementation of HMAC. In the end it *looks* like a double salt mechanism, but that's not quite the case. I suggest reading the security proof behind it for more details.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray *A message digest is not the same thing as a signature.* I'm not sure what you're getting at with this.. Facebook's page that the question referred to [calls it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#usingsignedrequest) a *signature*, which I followed suit in my answer, while [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) calls `hash_hmac`'s return value a *message digest*.  One or the other may not be technically correct w.r.t HMAC's spec, but I'm pretty sure we're all talking about `hash_hmac`'s return value.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray *the HMAC key is a key and it is not a salt, it is integrated using a mixing function described in the specification* Are you saying that the HMAC function will produce an output that's less than N-bit strength if fed a key/secret of length N where N is less than 256?  In that case, doing so is indeed bad and not recommended.  I gathered from the Wikipedia article, albeit with my limited knowledge, that this wasn't the case, and drew the conclusion that the key, like a salt, brings no ill-proportional sufferings by being shorter than the practical maximum.

Comment: I know it's a bit late to the conversation, but some may be interested in [this question on crypto.se which discusses the difference between a signature, a MAC, and a hash](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/what-are-the-differences-between-a-digital-signature-a-mac-and-a-hash). The three are in fact, not the same, despite the fact that "signature" is often times inappropriately used in place of "MAC" by those who are not familiar enough with the concepts.

Answer (score 10):

HMAC takes the HASH(key) and uses it as the key if the length of the key is greater than the internal block size of the hash. Thus, a key larger than the internal block size of the hash provides no better security than one of equal size. Shorter keys are zero padded to be equal to the internal block size of the hash as per the HMAC specification.

It's impossible to use a 128-bit key with HMAC-SHA-256. If you mean 128 bits padded out to 512 bits with zeroes, then it's probably alright for short-term authentication. I'd recommend at least 256 bits and ideally you would want to use something equal to the internal block size of the underlying hash.

Comment: No sure how [PHP's `hash_hmac` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) handles keys that are not long enough.